# Run custom function ( for decoding url ) in spreedsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I export my search console result , because my Urls is persian it show that like this in spreed sheet .

[image]

I write a custom function for that .This is my custom function :

```
function decode(value) {
  return decodeURIComponent(value);
}
```

But my problem is i need run this function in the entire of column . how can i do this ? I need write decoded url in the front of same row with it . like this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do, check it out.

```
function test1()
{
    var sp = SpreadsheetApp.openById("my_spreadsheet_id").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var data = sp.getRange("A1:A").getValues().filter(String);

      for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
      {
        var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(data[i]);
        sp.getRange("F"+(i+1)).setValue(uri_dec);
      }
}
```

Comment: You can get the `spreadsheet_id` from the url of the spreadsheet. And in place of `Sheet1` place the name of worksheet (look at the bottom of the spreadsheet). Of course you'll have to authorize the script first(it's a one time procedure)

Comment: This worked but it should be begin from f2 cell because A1 is a title and it is pages